Serverless Framework App Sync Plugin - Add AWS Managed Rule
I have tried to use the documentation for the App Sync plugin to add an AWS managed rule but I am unable to get it add the rule, instead I get the following error:
Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: GraphQlWaf (AWS::WAFv2::WebACL)
Resource handler returned message: "Error reason: A reference in your rule statement is not valid., field: RULE, parameter: Statement (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 5ae443c0-da15-4ef8-8734-2bc8d2365822)" (RequestToken: 6e51723d-08dd-68da-f0e7-ecfc51c29a4e, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Here is my configuration:
waf:
    enabled: true
    defaultAction: "Allow"
    rules:
      - name: "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
        priority: 20
        overrideAction:
          None: {}
        statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            VendorName: "AWS"
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"

Adding a single throttle rule works as expected:
- throttle: 1000

The example is the sample yaml from the documentation but for some unknown reason I get this error. If anyone has a working example or can tell me what is causing this error then please let me know.

Unfortunately this was my issue, I examined the generated cloud formation template and I noticed that in the JSON file it was never actually adding the overrideAction block, and the error from AWS is very vague.
I tried adding the action block as a test and I noted that this was added to the JSON, although it was malformed, so I upgraded the plugin to the latest version in my package.json and it seems to work as expected now. The correct block is added to the JSON template and the rules are added to my WAF.
